# Bootstrap responsive table not acting responsively

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapper

I am working on the code below, and am trying to find out:

1. Why the table is not acting responsive
2. I want able to control `<td>` widths by using `col-md-3` and `col-lg-3`; does this works in table as well?

Here is the code I have:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-1  col-lg-offset-1 col-md-6    col-lg-6">
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="174"><strong>7:30 – 8:45 a.m.</strong></td>
<td>Arrival / Health CheckFree Choice in Activity Areas, books, puzzles, matching games, large block building, small blocks, floor toys, Lego, trucks and car play.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>8:45 – 9:00 a.m.</strong></td>
<td>Clean-up, toileting, wash up for snack</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>9:00 – 9:30 a.m.</strong></td>
<td>Morning snack</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>9:30 -10:00 a.m.</strong></td>
<td>Circle Time: Action songs, singing time, finger plays, hello songs, discussion of daily activities</td>
</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

As you can see I couldn't control the table size with `col-md-3` and  `col-lg-3`, so I wrapped it in a div but the responsiveness is not working.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Please re-read [the docs on this feature](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive). The `table-responsive` class needs to be on a wrapper div, not the table itself.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, how about width of the td ? can we control them by col-**-* classes?

Comment: The `col-*` classes just set a percentage width, which'll work similar to just doing `<td width="10%">`.

Comment: Without `<div class="table-responsive">` also tables are responsive in my side.  I use only table class. I don't know how it happens.

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally read the documentation for bootstrap 4 alpha, where you indeed need to add this class to the table directly, not the wrapper. At least the example shows it that way. So this might change in the future.

Comment: This does not work if table-responsive div is inside a table's td. Any solution?? Please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.table-responsive` should be on wrapper div because even if you use css property `overflow:scroll` scrollbar will not active on table tag so we are using a wrapper div with class `table-responsive` to show to scroll bar to make table responsive.

This is the reason we need to write responsive table code like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work if table-responsive div is inside a table's td. Any solution?? Please suggest me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It does work to set the `table-responsive` class on the table itself if you also set the table to `display: block`. It's generally better to just use the wrapper `div` though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrap all my tables with the following class.  Bootstrap or otherwise and it works every time.

```css
.respTable {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   margin: 5px;
}
```